# How can I see my website like a color blind person?

Tags: accessibility

Is there some kind of plugin or service for any browser out there (Mac OS, Windows or Linux) that would let me see a website like a colorblind person would?

Comment: If you have further accessibility questions, you may want to check out the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71/what-are-good-resources-for-testing-ui-design-for-color-blind-users) StackExchange site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This website](http://colorfilter.wickline.org/) seems to do what you need.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to depend on a web service, [Chrometric](http://enably.com/chrometric/) is a free AIR-based browser that lets you toggle between different forms of color blindness. It also has the advantage of working in a live browser (such as WebKit), rather than for single URLs at a time.

There's also a [colorblindness simulator add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorblind-simulator/) for Firefox.